# Finding all real solutions of algebraic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1.) Solve the equation for the indicated variable: $S = n(n + 1)/3$;   for $n$.

My answer: $n = 1+\sqrt{ 1+12s}/2$ , $1+\sqrt{ 1+12s}/2$. For some reason I keep getting this as incorrect?

2.) Find all real solutions of the quadratic equation: $7y^2 − y − 1/7 = 0$

My answer: $y= 1/14 (1-3\sqrt{53})$ , $1/14(1+3\sqrt{53})$

3.) Find all real solutions of the equation.  $x^{4/3} − 5x^{2/3} + 6 = 0$

My answer: $2\sqrt{2}$ , $3\sqrt{3}$.

I don't understand why I keep getting these wrong. Please explain, thank you in advance.

Comment: For the first one the solutions are $\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+12S}}{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That is what the OP obtained.

Comment: @SDevalapurkar:  My display is poor, but I do not see a $-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'd dismiss that as a typo, but, technically, you're right.

Comment: @SDevalapurkar: Grading programs are not as forgiving of typos as you and I are.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Of course.

Comment: For the second, rewrite as $49x^2-7x-1=0$ and then use the Quadratic Formula carefully.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, rewrite as follows:
$$n^2+n=3S\implies n^2+n-3S=0$$
For the last, write:
$$(x^{2/3})^2+5x^{2/3}+6=0$$
For all of them, use the quadratic formula:

> If $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then
>   $$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

I think you messed up on the formula; redo the problems again with this formula - you should get the right answers.

Answer (score 0):

After reworking it the answers I got were:

1.) Solve the equation for the indicated variable. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

S = n(n + 1)/3; for n

My answer: √(3s+1/4)-1/2 , -1/2-√(3s+1/4)

2.) Find all real solutions of the quadratic equation. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If there is no real solution, enter NO REAL SOLUTION.) 7y^2 − y − 1/7 = 0

My answer: y = 1/14 + √5/14, 1/14 - √5/14

3.) Find all real solutions of the equation. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If there is no real solution, enter NO REAL SOLUTION.) x^(4/3) − 5x^(2/3) + 6 = 0

My answer: 3√3, 2√2

How does this all look?

Comment: Your answers are correct.  However, you can simplify $$-\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{3s + \frac{1}{4}}$$ by obtaining a common denominator, then extracting a factor of $1/2$ from the square root.  $$-\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{3s + \frac{1}{4}} = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{12s + 1}{4}} = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{1 + 12s}}{2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 12s}}{2}$$